# NSDates in a UITableView Section are not reflecting dates from a UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsdate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple application with a `UITableViewController` which is populated by a user filling in a and selecting a date from a `UIDatePicker` in a different view. The `cells` of the `UITableView` are populated with the words from the `UITextField` and the `UITableView` `section` title represents the selected date from the `UIDatePicker`.

When the user saves in the `Add Entry View Controller,` it is saved to `Core Data` and `NSFetchedResultsController` is responsible for updating the `UITableView`.

In a previous version of my app (version 2.0), I had a bug where the American timezone would always show the section title as one day prior to the selected date from the `UIDatePicker`. It was fine for other countries. The NSDate was being stored with a UTC timezone.

I implemented a fix by setting the `UIDatePicker` to not use any timezone for version 2.1.1. I thought that fixed it, but further testing has lead me to discover other bugs.

I am now trying to fix this.

I have a `Transient` property for the section titles as below:

```
-(NSString *)sectionDateFormatter
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy"];

    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

    NSDate *thisDate = self.dates.dateOfEvent;
    NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.dates.dateOfEvent];
    NSLog(@"[Transaction] The NSDate of self.dates.dateOfEvent = %@", thisDate);
    NSLog(@"[Transaction] The NSDate converted into a string = %@", stringDate);

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.dates.dateOfEvent];

}
```

My model is: a `Transaction Entity` with a relationship to the `Dates Entity`, and `datesOfEvent` is a `NSDate`. I am converting this to a string so it is easily displayed in my desired format as the `section` title.

**Problem**

If I start with a new installation of my app, this works really well and in the `Add Entry View Controller`, I have set the `UIDatePicker` to use the GMT timezone as well.

However, if I update from version 2.1.1, ALL of my EXISTING* entries have their dates moved back by one in the `section` title of the `UITableView`. What I mean by this is:

If I have 1 entry for the 17th September, one entry for the 15th and one for the 10th (just an example of dates) in version 2.1.1, when I update to this new version that I'm working on, all of the section titles go back by one date to the 16th September, 14th and 9th September. If I click on the entry, the `UIDatePicker` will show the date it's supposed to be (not what is displayed in the `section` title). So if I click on the first entry, the `UIDatePicker` shows me the 17th, but the `section` title shows me the 16th.

This is regardless of timezone.

I'm not really sure what I need to do to make sure updated users have the same dates, and new users don't have issues as well. Why is everything moving back by one date?

When I run the app after updating, the NSLogs output show:
[Transaction] The NSDate of self.dates.dateOfEvent = 2014-09-16 23:00:00 +0000
[Transaction] The NSDate converted into a string = 16 September 2014

I don't understand why `dateOfEvent` is 16th at 23:00 and the string is showing 16th. I don't get why the dates move one date back.

*EXISTING: I have this clearly marked because new entries in the updated version work fine, but the existing entries are the ones that have their dates moved back in the section titles.

Please keep in mind that with version 2.1.1, I did not have the code to use GMT in the `Transient` property for the `section` title. That is just something I've introduced now while developing, as a result of some strange behaviour with timezones.

**Update: Showing how the dates are stored**

In a save method of the Add Entry, in version 2.1.1, I am doing this:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
//cal.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                      fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
//[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSDate *selectedDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

// Call the date category and check whether the value exists; if it does return, etc.
Date *date = (Date *)[Date occasionWithDate:selectedDate inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

So, I had put in the localTimeZone for the calendar and the NSDateComponents, but I commented out the code in the shipped version of 2.1.1.

In version 2.0, I have:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                      fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *selectedDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

// Call the date category and check whether the value exists; if it does return, etc.
Date *date = (Date *)[Date occasionWithDate:selectedDate inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

I am setting the timezone of the NSDateComponents to UTC.

In version 2.2 (the version I am working on), I am setting this:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                      fromDate:self.datePicker.date];

self.datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
components.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]; 

NSDate *selectedDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
// Call the date category and check whether the value exists; if it does return, etc.
Date *date = (Date *)[Date occasionWithDate:selectedDate inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

I am setting this to the GMT timezone.

Any assistance on this would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDate contains a point in time in UTC (which is roughly Greenwich Mean Time without daylight savings time). It has not time zone information. If we both look at our watches at the same moment, we probably see different times because we are in different locations. But we see the same result if our apps call [NSDate date] at the same moment.

You should always store NSDate unmodified and use NSTimeZone and NSDateFormatter methods to display the time to the user. It's absolutely normal if NSLog (@"%@", [NSDate date])) displays things that are unexpected to you, because it displays the time in UTC. The text displayed to your user through NSDateFormatter should be different.

I'd say you need to step back from what you are doing and find out what exactly you have been storing for existing dates. Did you store the correct NSDate or did you store it somehow adjusted for time zones? If your new code is storing different NSDates for the same time, then obviously something cannot work.

Comment: thanks so much for the response @gnasher729 and your explanation really makes sense. I've updated my question to reflect the code that does the storing of dates. In version 2.0, I'm storing it as UTC. In 2.1.1, I am not setting a timezone at all (I had some strange issue and I thought NOT setting the timezone worked.. but it's caused this issue in this question) and in version 2.2 (the version I'm currently working on), I'm setting this to GMT. The problem is from 2.1.1 to 2.2 (2.0 to 2.1.1 is fine).. so with not setting a timezone, I've messed this up..

Comment: So it seems that the date shown to the user is what's messing up.. that it as a timezone set to it and that is somehow different from the UIDatePicker when upgrading. Also, it's important to mention that version 2.1.1 (and 2.0) did not have any timezones set in the sectionDateFormatter transient property; that is code that I have put in version 2.2 now.

Comment: I have a working solution, which is to go back to the point where the code worked, and then update the Transaction.m in the next release. It's a bit of a hack, but it does what I require. Thanks for your reply with this, it really helped point me in the right direction and I appreciate it massively!